# Not able to inject CommandService to execute the command manually

Tags: eclipse, e4, efxclipse

I have handler (to create new parts) assigned to particular command, which is defined as below and working fine,
**Handler class :**

```java
..
@Execute
public void execute(EPartService partService,MApplication application,EModelService modelService) {
    MPart part = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createPart();
    part.setLabel("New Part");
    part.setContributionURI("platform:/plugin/com.my.First.app/src/com/my/first/Parts/EditorPart/EmptyPart");
    List<MPartStack> stacks = modelService.findElements(application, null,  MPartStack.class, null);
    stacks.get(2).getChildren().add(part);
    partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
}

@Execute
public void execute() {
    //This Hello is getting printed.
    System.out.println("Hello ");
}
```

I have one controller class to control the Fxml Objects (the click event on treeView). I want to execute that command manually from event handler treeview.
**Controller Class :**

```java
@Inject
org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.ECommandService commandService;
@Inject
org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.EHandlerService service;
..
..

locationTreeView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 && mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)
                    && locationTreeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().isLeaf()) {
                try {
                    Command command = commandService.getCommand(S_CMD_MY_COMMAND_ID);
                    if (!command.isDefined())
                        return;
                    ParameterizedCommand myCommand = commandService.createCommand(S_CMD_MY_COMMAND_ID, null);
                    service.activateHandler(S_CMD_MY_COMMAND_ID, new ShowImmobilizerPart());
                    if (!service.canExecute(myCommand))
                        return;
                    service.executeHandler(myCommand);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Here, Injected CommandService is null so not able to execute this parametric execute method of my handler class.
I believe there is another [CommandService](http://git.eclipse.org/c/efxclipse/org.eclipse.efxclipse.git/commit/?id=9837bd2073d79e911d8cd1f2e3be966b18ab6465) (**org.eclipse.fx.core.command.CommandService**) for `e(fx)clipse` but that is also comming null. I am using that as below
**Controller Class :**

```java
@Inject org.eclipse.fx.core.command.CommandService commandService;
..
..
if (commandService.exists(S_CMD_MY_COMMAND_ID) && commandService.canExecute(S_CMD_MY_COMMAND_ID, null)) {
    commandService.execute(S_CMD_MY_COMMAND_ID, null);
}
```

---

**[Edit]** :
My aim is to open new Part in Partstack. So in first code snippet you can see how i am opening part in execute(..). Here, Is there any way to get partService , application and modelService using `ContextInjectionFactory` or `IEclipseContext`?
**Controller Class** :

```java
MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myHandler, iEclipseContext);
//myHandler.execute();  This is woroking if i define execute() method in handler Class.
myHandler.execute(partService,application,modelService); // This is not working as i am injecting this arguments at top of class.
```

Comment: How are you creating the Controller class? Injection is not done on classes created using `new`.

Comment: Hi greg, I am connecting my fxml to controller class (java) as explained here in link : https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to. And I am using FxmlLoader to load the fxml in view using postconstruct(Pane composite) in a e4 view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only classes created by Eclipse from descriptions in the e4xmi file are injected.

If you have a class created some other way you can do injection using:

```java
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(object, context);
```

where `object` is the class instance to be injected and `context` is the `IEclipseContext` to use. Note that this will not inject the Constructor.

You can also use `ContextInjectionFactory.make` to create a class using injection.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks first. That worked for `execute()` but i have to call `execute(EPartService partService,MApplication application,EModelService modelService)`. Do you know how i can get all these in my control class?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. All those things can be injected.

Comment: From Controller Class i need to call Handler's execute(EPartService partService,MApplication application,EModelService modelService) method which is defined in question.  
I am getting `NPE` while i inject `EPartService` , `MApplication` and  `EModelService `.   
So is there any way to call this handler manually from that controller class.

Comment: I think you need to add your new code to the question because I still don't follow what you are now doing.

Comment: please check now. Thanks

Comment: You should not run a Handler like that. The code using `ParameterizedCommand` is the correct way to run a handler. The ContextInjectionFactory.inject` call should be in the code using `FxmlLoader` to create the Controller class so that the Controller class is injected.

Comment: Hi greg, I am able to execute command now using.`ECommandService` and `EHandlerService` . Like said here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405293/2691625.